# Inserting data in mysql using vb.net (n-tier)

Tags: vb.net, n-tier-architecture

there's anyone can help me with my vb.codes? i'm new in vb.net and i want to know how to add data in mysql database using n-tier in vb.net. this is may current code in adding data:

Data Layer:

```
Public Function addData() As DataTable
    Dim myCommand As String = "Insert Into tblItems VALUES (@Itemcode, @Itemname, @Itemdescription, @Itemtype, @Itempricing, @Itemonstock, @Itemprice, @Datemod)"
    con.Open()
    Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand, con)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    sda.Fill(dt)
    Return dt
End Function
```

sorry for my code. i really don't know how can i use that in BLL and PL. please help me. i really want to learn from all of you guys..

PS: sorry for my english i'm a 14 yr old and i want to learn programming. i did a research but i can't find what i'm really looking for. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a new record in a datatable you need to execute a command and provide the values to be sent to the database table.

You need something like this.

```
Public Function addData(itmCode as String, itmName as String.... omitted the other values) As Integer
    Dim myCommand As String = "Insert Into tblItems VALUES " & _ 
                              "(@Itemcode, @Itemname, @Itemdescription, " & _
                               "@Itemtype, @Itempricing, @Itemonstock, @Itemprice, @Datemod)"
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(myCommand, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", itmCode)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", itmName)
    .... other parameters for the other values to insert will follow....

    Dim rowInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    return rowInserted
End Function
```

This requires that you pass to the function the values through a set of variables which values are added to the parameter collection of the command and finally execute the command.
The execution returns the number of records inserted/changed/deleted.

Notice also that your query doesn't specify a field list, so you need to pass the values to update every single field in the underlying datatable with the exact order.

Comment: hi sir. sir can you also provide the code on o how to call this codes from DL to BLL and PL ? please i'm begging you. :( i really want to learn. thanks sir.

Comment: Sorry but really I can't help on this. I don't know anything about your design, where do you get the input values, what libraries are involved. It 's just a little push to move you in the right direction

Comment: the `@itemCOde` and others is my column in mysql. due to the n-tier architecture, i can't replace `@itemCode` like this `'"& ItemCodetxt.text &"'` so i try to use like that to insert data inputed from my PL going to BLL to DL. :(